# Wrong rlimit information in hs_err_pidXXX.log file when JVM crashes

Tags: java, crash, jvm, ulimit

I have a java application running with jdk 1.8.0_102. When the application crashes (out of memory - see below) a file hs_err_pidXXX is generated with several information about the jvm, system, memory, threads etc...

```
    #
    # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory.
    # Possible reasons:
    #   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
    #   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
    # Possible solutions:
    #   Reduce memory load on the system
    #   Increase physical memory or swap space
    #   Check if swap backing store is full
    #   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
    #   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
    #   Decrease number of Java threads
    #   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
    #   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
    # This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
    #
    #  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=1094, tid=0x00007fac4041e700
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
```

...

```
    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"

    uname:Linux 3.13.0-101-generic #148-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 22:08:32 UTC 2016 x86_64
    libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19 
    rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 30034, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
    load average:10.38 6.50 2.88
```

In the list of information above, i can see the following line:
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 30034, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity

My question is the following:
why NOFILE does not correspond to the value I have set on my system (in limits.conf file, it should be 20000)? When I run the command ulimit -n with the same user as the one running the jvm, i have a different value. Note that STACK displayed is the correct value that I have set on my system, not the default one.
JVM is run on AWS c3.large on demand instance.

Here is the result of the ulimit -a command :

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30034
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 20000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30034
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: I would worry about why the application is crashing first, but you are right the numbers should match.

Comment: What does `ulimit -a` say?

Comment: We do worry about the crash reason but the question was about the mismatching value between the NOFILE value set in our system and the value displayed in the crash log.

Comment: @Stephen C : I edited the post with the ulimit -a command result

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code <sup>1</sup>.  It turns out that the rlimit values that are printed in the dump are being obtained by calling `getrlimit`.  That is a POSIX library method that is getting the info directly from the OS.  The JVM does not reduce its NOFILES rlimit, though in some circumstances, it will *increase* the soft rlimit to the value of the hard rlimit.

So, I suspect that the rlimit that is reported in the dump *must be* set in the environment that is launching the JVM that runs your application.  This cannot be the same environment as the shell where you ran `ulimit`.

---

<sup>1 - ...using `find` and `grep`, so it is possible that I missed something.</sup>

Comment: thanks for your help.

As an addition, here is our configuration for the nofile in /etc/security/limits.conf

# End of file
* soft nofile 20000
* hard nofile 20000

This sets the same values for all users plus we do run the jvm with the same user we used to run the ulimit -a command.

Comment: That may be so.  However, it appears that when the JVM is >>launched<< the rlimits are different.  You need to figure out why that is.  For what it is worth, it is a simple matter to install mercurial and then fetch the Java source code for yourself.  That will allow you to repeat the analysis I performed.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if your process is being started by another user via the `runuser` or `su` commands.

e.g.

```
  user1: NPROC = 1024
  user2: NPROC = 4096

user1>  runsuser -c MyApp user2
user1> ps -fu user2

UID   PID   CMD
user2 1234  MyApp

user1> grep processes /proc/1234/limits

Max processes  1024  128321  processes
```

So here we can see that, although the process is running as user2, who has an NPROC of 4096, the process has inherited the NPROC value of 1024 from user1.

This caught us out on our system, as our application is run via IBM Tivoli Workload Scheduler, which you can't spot by running a simple `ps` command.  However, this would happen with anything that is performing the equivalent of `runuser` or `su`.